# Assistance with mathematics for fiction project

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I am working on a project to develop a rigorously mathematically-defined magic system. The "magical energy" (which is in units of energy) is quantized in what effectively amounts to extremely high energy photons, and therefore the momentum is defined as:

$p = \dfrac{h}{\lambda}$

From here, this energy can be stored within an object, however the energy will radiate from the object over time as the magical energy particles move around inside the object. Given that the magical energy particles will interact (which is to say bounce off of) the particles inside the containing object as they move around inside, I have defined this rate as:

$ \dfrac{d \psi}{dt} = \dfrac{(p \cdot \delta)}{(D \cdot d)}$

Where delta is the energy density contained within the object, D is the density of the containing object, and d is the average linear distance a magical particle must travel to escape the bounds of the object.

What I now want to calculate is the amount of time it would take for amount of energy in the containing object to completely radiate away. When thinking about it, it seems like the radioactive decay rate equation is close to what I need ( N(t) = N(0)e^(-lambda t) ), however that uses a time-independent rate (I noticed that the decay rate equation is almost exactly identical to the compound interest equation, which itself assumes a constant interest rate over time), whereas if my rate is proportional to the energy density, which will decrease over time as the energy radiates away, then it stands to reason that my rate will also decrease over time, and is therefore time-dependent.

Comment: Hi. Not 100% I understood what you mean but from what I understood, it would be a radioactive-like decay. Did you check the units in your equation? What are the units of each term?

Comment: @Arnaud
energy is in units [mass][length]^2[time]^-2
energy density is in units [mass][length]^-1[time]^-2
momentum is in units [mass][length]^-1[time]^-1
density is in units [mass][length]^-3
linear distance is in units [length]. It's all in SI units.

Comment: Thanks. What unit is Psi ? I think I found: Psi is an energy quantity, and d Psi / dt is a power quantity. Right?

Comment: I confirm, with the clarification of what psi means, that the units match on each side of the equation. Next question : are lambda, D and d constant over time?

Comment: @Arnaud D and d are constant, however lambda is not, as lambda represents the magical energy density in the object, which can be represented as energy per cubic meter. Hence, as the magical energy is radiated over time, this energy density will decrease over time.

Comment: You meant delta, not lambda.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, sorry. Lambda is constant as well, but delta is not.

Comment: Good :) So, is lambda also constant (and unique : all your photons have the same non-varying wavelength)?

Comment: @Arnaud That is correct!

Answer (score 1):

If you call $E$ the total magical energy contained in the object then $\delta = E/V$ where $V$ is the volume of the object. So you can rewrite your equation
$$\frac{dE}{dt} = - \frac{p}{V\cdot D\cdot d}E$$
and the solution is
$$E(t)=E(0) e^{-at}$$
with $a=\frac{p}{VDd}$.